# Return statement not working when calling another method

Tags: java, return, bluej, method-call

I have recently started experimenting with the return statement, and I have a small doubt relating to it- When I have a method which calls another method, will the return statement of that method which I am calling be displayed?

Let be give an example to make it clearer-

```
/** Program to test return statment */

public class Test
{
   public static void main(int a)
   {
      EvenOrOdd(a);
   }
   private static boolean EvenOrOdd(int a)
   {//I can declare as public and run directly but then what is the point in calling     the method?
      if(a%2==0) 
      {
        System.out.println("The output is true.");//Displays
        return true;//Does not display(As in that window does not pop up with the result.)
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("The output is false.");//Displays  
        return false;//Does not display
      }

   }
}
```

If I were to simply remove the main method(or even make the second method public and run that directly), my return statement is displayed however if I attempt to call the method and run the program my return statement isn't displayed.

So is this just a problem I am facing or is it a general rule in Java that the return statement doesn't work when you call another method(which has a return statement)?

If it is the latter, then I apologise, I was not aware of this.

Thanks...

```
                               ***UPDATE***
```

It seems that nobody has understood what I exactly mean. I will give another example-

Please run this program-:

```
/** Program to test Return statment;simple program to return sum of two digits */

public class Return_Test
{
   public static int main(int a,int b)
   {
    return a+b;//What I am lloking for is that box in which this is displayed.
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any where it should display...

Comment: @Eran This is BlueJ and allows you to accept any data type you wish to as input in the main method.

Comment: Seems like you are missing a `System.out.println`. Add this statement `System.out.println(EvenOrOdd(a));` to display the return of the function

Comment: @JackSully BlueJ is a useful tool when learning the basic of Programming  it helps put off complex syntax for later , One can Inspect return values even without an Terminal I/O such as System.out.println(""),I'm not sure how its done though , I suggest you follow either that way of learning or the conventional way , ie to expose yourself to the syntax early on ignoring any keywords you don’t understand , typing it as such , later when you come to that part after learning the basics you can explore that ...

Comment: @DroidIcs Hmmm...You're right,I guess I must be patient. Thanks...

Comment: You must understand that BlueJ is only a tool that aids learning by hiding certain details early on,normally  the main should only be _public static void main(String[] args)_ under ordinary circumstances and what a 'return x;' statement  means is 'give x back to the caller' ,eg `x=method(); int method(){int y=5;return y;}`, x is merely assigned to y and **nowhere is the code to display it present**, So you should put a Statement like System.out.println(x)  or System.out.println(method());..Hope that clears it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a lot of other responders don't know is that when you run a method in BlueJ, it executes the method, and if the the return value of the method is non-void, it is shown in a popup dialog by invoking toString.  That's what the questioner means by the value being displayed.

The answer to the user's original question is that by surrounding the method with a void return, it "hides" the result.  So this code:

```
public void callMe1(int a)
{
    EvenOrOdd(a);
}
```

will not display the return.  But if you adjust the return type and actually return the value of the inner call:

```
public int callMe2(int a)
{
    return EvenOrOdd(a);
}
```

Then BlueJ will display the returned value.  The display aspect is down to BlueJ, but the rules for whether or not the value gets returned are the same as in Java; void means no return.

Answer (score 1):

A return statement only returns the value ,*does not Display it* 
If you don’t catch the return value , how can it be displayed? add something like this and try
,

```
public class Test
{
   public static void main(int a)
   {
    boolean temp=EvenOrOdd(a);
    if(temp)
    System.out.println("Output is True");
    else
    System.out.println("Output False(not even )");
    //Or you can directly call the method as' System.out.println(EvenOrOdd));'

   }
   private static boolean EvenOrOdd(int a)
   {//I can declare as public and run directly but then what is the point in calling     the method?
      if(a%2==0) 
      {
        System.out.println("The output is true.");//Displays
        return true;//Does not display
      }
      else
      {
        System.out.println("The output is false.");//Displays  
        return false;//Does not display
      }

   }
}
```

And Please try learning some good Naming Conventions , Classes are Named like this ,
FirstSecond,TestException(Each Word Starts with a Capital Letter) etc , methods start with a small letter , isPrime() , isEven(),

Comment: No @MadProgrammer, no. Don't do recursion. Good suggestion, but not the way the op has programmed it.

Comment: I never said anything about recursion...you just don't need to modify the `EvenOrOdd` method (from your original answer), just display the result from the method...

Comment: did your program produce output?

Answer (score 0):

Within the body of the method, you use the `return statement to return the value`. It will not print anything on its own.

Changes done - `System.out.println(EvenOrOdd(5));`

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(EvenOrOdd(5));
    }

    private static boolean EvenOrOdd(int a) {// I can declare as public and run directly but then what is the point in
                                             // calling the method?
        if (a % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("The output is true.");// Displays
            return true;// Does not display
        } else {
            System.out.println("The output is false.");// Displays
            return false;// Does not display
        }

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
The output is false.
false
```

Answer (score 0):

first change your main signature from `main(int a)` to `main(String [] args)` otherwise you will get following runtime exception :

```
Error: Main method not found in class yourpackagename.Test, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

well you didn't print the value return from function :

in your `main` do this:

```
System.out.println(EvenOrOdd(5));
```

Comment: FYI: *"This is BlueJ and allows you to accept any data type you wish to as input in the main method"*

Comment: Yeah, I've never used it either :P

Answer (score 0):

1. You never actually display the return result from the method...
2. The name of the method is consuming `EvenOrOdd` returning `true` or `false` is ambigious, may `isEven` would be better...

You could try something like...

```
System.out.println(a + " is even = " + EvenOrOdd(a));
```

You should also avoid using multiple `return` statements within a single method, it can quickly become confusing as to how the method actually works, in your case, you can reduce the over complexity at the same time, for example...

```
private static boolean isEven(int a)
{

    boolean isEven = false;
    if(a%2==0) 
    {
        System.out.println("The output is true.");//Displays
        isEven = true;//Does not display
    }

    return isEven;

}
```